# Diiferent types of input in function

Tags: c#, libraries

I'm making my first library and I want to make different types of input( example: Graphics.DrawLine(); can be determined by four floats or by two points, etc.) How do I make a similar thing?

Comment: It's called overloads, you basically declare the same method multiple times with different parameter types and number of parameters. A typical implementation could be that all the overloads all call the same single one of them that has the actual implementation, or you have a private method they all call that contains it. Example: `public void Initialize(Point p, Size s) { ... } public void Initialize(int x, int y, int w, int h) { ... }`.

Comment: Note that your overloads must actually differ by parameter types or number of parameters. It is not enough to simply rename the parameters, the actual types or number of them has to differ.

Comment: You can read more about it here - [Member Overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just create multiple methods with different arguments.

For example:

```
public class MyGraphics
{

    public bool Draw(Vector2 position, bool big = false)
    {
    }

    public void Draw(Line2 line)
    {
    }
    public void Draw(Triangle2 triangle)
    {
    }

    public void Draw(Polygon2 polygon)
    {
    }

    public void Draw(Line2[] edges)
    {
    }
}
```

to be used later as

```
{
    MyGraphics g = ...
    Line2 line = ...
    Triangle2 trig = ...

    g.Draw(line);  // calls `.Draw(Line2)`
    g.Draw(trig);  // calls `.Draw(Triangle2)`
}
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well, to be fair, it's both :) Overloaded extension methods...

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok, made them into plain methods

Comment: @ColinM - when I said `it` I meant the overloading.